# Loading Component with Custom Properties (without setSource)

Tags: qt, qml

Say I have a QML Application with a toolbar:

```qml
ApplicationWindow {
  header: MyTools {
    showAdminButtons: userIsAdmin()
  }
}
```

I can dynamically pick the component to show by using a [`Loader`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-loader.html):

```qml
ApplicationWindow {
  header: Loader {
    source: Qt.platform.os=="linux" ? "qrc:/linux/MyTools.qml" : "qrc:/MyTools.qml"
  }
}
```

However, if I want to supply custom property values to that component (like `showAdminButtons` above), I must use the `setSource()` method:

```
ApplicationWindow {
  header: Loader {
    Component.onCompleted: {
      var qml = Qt.platform.os=="linux" ? "qrc:/linux/MyTools.qml" : "qrc:/MyTools.qml";
      setSource( qml, {showAdminButtons:userIsAdmin()} );
    }
  }
}
```

Is there a "QML-only" way to supply properties to a Loader, that does not require `Component.onCompleted`? (I cannot fully justify why `Component.onCompleted` feels like a gross hack workaround to me, but it does, every time I have to use it. It's something to do with the declarative nature of QML vs. the procedural nature of JS.)

Comment: I've discovered [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27704424/405017) which sort of solves my question. However, it appears to work only if I remove properties from my components' signatures and instead define them to require the instantiation to pass values in. It prevents property aliases and default values from working.

Comment: A technique called "file selectors" is superior compared to Loader + Qt.platform.os: http://www.ics.com/blog/mastering-qt-file-selectors

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Method 1: binding (or a simple assignment if binding is not necessary) when [`Loader.onLoaded`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-loader.html#loaded-signal):

```
ApplicationWindow {
    header: Loader {
        source: Qt.platform.os=="linux" ? "qrc:/linux/MyTools.qml" : "qrc:/MyTools.qml"
        onLoaded: {
            item.showAdminButtons = Qt.binding(function() { return userIsAdmin(); }
        }
    }
}
```

Method 2: use [`Binding`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-binding.html) type:

```
ApplicationWindow {
    header: Loader {
        id: loader
        source: Qt.platform.os=="linux" ? "qrc:/linux/MyTools.qml" : "qrc:/MyTools.qml"
        Binding {
            target: loader.item
            property: "showAdminButtons"
            value: userIsAdmin()
        }
    }
}
```